# problem on placing the correct annotation

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, scatter-plot

I used scatter to plot two points (p1(0.2,0.5), p2(0.3,0.8)) on a figure on a GUI (tinker), then tried to add the text for each point. However, the text was located on the figure based on the ratio of figure (for example, 'p1' located at 20% width and 50% height of the figure.

```
import tkinter
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'x': [0.2, 0.3], 'y': [0.5, 0.8], 'point': ["p1", "p2"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

root = tkinter.Tk()

figure= plt.Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
figure.add_subplot(111).scatter(df['x'],df['y'])

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    figure.text(row['x'], row['y'], row['point'])

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

tkinter.mainloop()
```

am I missing anything to place the text at the correct location. I really want to plot figure on tkinker

---

[image]

Comment: You need to add the text to the subplot (`ax`), not to the figure. `ax = figure.add_subplot(111)` and then `ax.scatter(df['x'],df['y'])` and `ax.text(row['x'], row['y'], '  ' + row['point'])`.